# Fullscreen and clickable area (Internet browser)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've made a game that is displayed by a  tag. It can be displayed fullscreen on an Internet browser when you click on a button, but...

When I go fullscreen, the clickable area only matches the initial size of the canvas, which means that the you can only interact with the game through a small square on the top left screen.

I've figured that, somehow, if I press F11, then F10, it works perfectly. But if I press F10 without setting my browser to fullscreen mode first, the "fullscreen" of the canvas is actually a small square appearing on the top left of the screen, over a black background, not even resized...

Unfortunatly, what I call a "game" is intended to an audience that is not familiar at all with the Internet. So this would be really inconvenient to ask people to press "F11", then "F10" to set the... well, it's annoying.

So, here's my question: is there a way to "emulate" that "f11, f10 combo"?

My actual code is:

```
<script>
function goFullScreen(){
var elem = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
}
        </script>

        <p><button onclick="goFullScreen();">Go fullscreen</button></p>
```

For some reason, this, above, is not equal to "F11, then F10..." How ?!

Thanks for reading.

Edit (additional informations):

- I tried it on edge and mozilla firefox (The behaviour is nearly the same)
- I'm not using devtools.
- The size of my canvas is set basically, as follow:
- This above is not linked to any relevant or tricky .css content.
- For the html part, the code I pasted is nearly the whole content of the page.
- Finally, concerning the click events, I don't know what to say, this is pretty basics: a button, an onclick event linked to the function pasted above. Concerning the game by itself, it shouldn't interfere since it doesn't if I set the browser in fullscreen (with "F11" key), then the content of the page in fullscreen (with the "F10" key). Any other way doesn't work properly.

Comment: F10? Which browser? are you in Devtools (F10 to step over). Anyways need to see the code that resizes the canvas (if you are resizing it) and the code that sets up the mouse events and the event handlers and also HTML / CSS of relevant elements will help you get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was totally relevant. I've added the missing informations you noticed to my initial post.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API - note the section about width/height 100%, and also check the debug console.

Comment: Thank you. I've reproduce that code line by line, and the same result happened: the game is displayed in fullscreen, but the active area is just a top left square with the dimension previously settled. However, one thing bother me: if I change the width and height to a percentage value (100%), the game is ridiculously small, like about 10px wide and 10 pixels in height, which doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

As we can not see the relevant javascript, html, or css we are left to guess.

My guess is that you are not resizing the canvas and/or what ever element you are getting the mouse events from.

You need to have a resize event that will resize elements when the page size is changed, including the fullscreen resize.

```
// add a listener to the window resize event
addEventListener("resize",function(){
     canvas.width = innerWidth;  // This sets the resolution of the canvas
     canvas.height = innerHeight; // to match the page size.
     // As i don't see your CSS to be safe set it to pixels and match the canvas resolution
     canvas.style.width = innerWidth + "px"; // must be in pixel units
     canvas.style.height = innerHeight + "px"; // must be in pixel units

     // to play safe set to absolute positioning
     canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     canvas.style.top = "0px";
     canvas.style.left = "0px";



     // You also need to change the element that is getting the mouse
     // input (if not the canvas)
     // Calling it mouseElement 
     mouseElement.style.width = "100%";
     mouseElement.style.height = "100%";
     mouseElement.style.position = "absolute";
     mouseElement.style.top = "0px";
     mouseElement.style.left = "0px";

 }
```

The following is how you can toggle between fullscreen and not.

```
// This function must be called from some type of user input (ie a mouse click event)
function toggleFullScreen() {
  const doc = document;
  if (!doc.fullscreenElement && !doc.mozFullScreenElement && !doc.webkitFullscreenElement && !doc.msFullscreenElement ) {  
    const docEl = document.documentElement;
    if (docEl.requestFullscreen) { docEl.requestFullscreen() }
    else if (docEl.msRequestFullscreen) { docEl.msRequestFullscreen() }
    else if (docEl.mozRequestFullScreen) { docEl.mozRequestFullScreen() }
    else if (docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen) { docEl.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT) }
  } else {
    if (doc.exitFullscreen) { doc.exitFullscreen() }
    else if (doc.msExitFullscreen) { doc.msExitFullscreen() }
    else if (doc.mozCancelFullScreen) { doc.mozCancelFullScreen() }
    else if (doc.webkitExitFullscreen) { doc.webkitExitFullscreen() }
  }
}
```

The above code will trigger a resize event.